# Service fabric upgrade

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I have a service fabric application type deployed to a cluster. This is working ok. I have recently refactored the code and  and changed the deployed application-name from A.. to B.. i.e. changed the application name in the type. After deploying to the cluster the following error is shown:

```
The update of 'ServiceTypeName' is not allowed. Current value 'A..' , Target value 'B..'. (Code: UpdateNotAllowed).
```

Any idea how to fix it I have tried deleting the old application type from the cluster before the update but that hasn't help.

Comment: @Daniel Mann what did you do eventually?

Comment: @ayeletkalderon This isn't my question. I only updated the tags on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy a new instance (instead of upgrading) and use [backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-backuprestoreservice-quickstart-azurecluster) & [restore](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-backup-restore-service-trigger-restore.md) to copy the data.